# How to parse a JSONString To Dataset?

Tags: c#, json, type-conversion

I am creating a C# Application using Web Services. In my Web Services I'm using a `JSONString` data.
But I'm not able to convert this string into a `DataSet`.

My `JSONString` is :

```
{
    "Table": [
        {
            "DisplayVoucherNumber": "A101239Z",
            "ActualDate": "08/07/2013",
            "AccountName": "shyamal",
            "Pcs": "50",
            "Weight": "500.000"
        }
    ],
    "Table1": [
        {
            "DisplayVoucherNumber": "R101249B",
            "ActualDate": "11/07/2013",
            "AccountName": "vipul",
            "NetWeight": "90.000",
            "Weight": "80.000",
            "Difference": "10.000"
        },
        {
            "DisplayVoucherNumber": "R101249B",
            "ActualDate": "11/07/2013",
            "AccountName": "vipul",
            "NetWeight": "500.000",
            "Weight": "100.000",
            "Difference": "400.000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i had try to that JSONString convert to DataSet and that Dataset value bind in Table.

Comment: it obviously doesn't deserialize into a dataset... it looks like a collection name value pair collecions

Comment: so how to bind data in table from JSONString. Here i have use multiple table to JSONString.

Comment: C# will automatically deserialize JSON to an object. I would recommend creating an object. The example string you gave would be deserialized as a List<object>. No need to deal with a Dataset.

Comment: Also see **this answer** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. I guess that what you would like to do is get back an object that could be mapped to you data set after deserializtion.
Something like

```
DataSet myDataSet= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonstring)
```

And you keep going coding with you dataset. like accessing datatables inside the dataset.

If it's what you want to achieve and don't want to use your own POCO as suggested by previous answers.
You might need to create a Typed DataSet before

> Given an XML Schema that complies with the XML Schema definition language (XSD) standard, you can generate a strongly typed DataSet using the XSD.exe tool provided with the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK).
>   [More info on strongly typed Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wha85tzb.aspx)

This will allow you to use the strongly typed dataset using the Deserialize method.

Bare in mind that you have to mimic your JSon Structure in the XML Schema.
in order to have something compatible with your JSon Structure at the end.

Answer (score 15):

As a *dynamic* C# solution(when you don't know the object structure to deserialize) by using @Dhaval's answer and after invaliding `Deserialize<>()` method I use below method to do that:

Update: `DataSet.ReadXml` has some options in reading XML node as [`XmlReadMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.xmlreadmode(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static DataSet ReadDataFromJson(string jsonString, XmlReadMode mode = XmlReadMode.Auto)
{
    //// Note:Json convertor needs a json with one node as root
    jsonString = $"{{ \"rootNode\": {{{jsonString.Trim().TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}')}}} }}";
    //// Now it is secure that we have always a Json with one node as root 
    var xd = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonString);

    //// DataSet is able to read from XML and return a proper DataSet
    var result = new DataSet();
    result.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(xd), mode);
    return result;
}
```

E.g. If you want to infer a strongly typed schema from the data:

```
var dataset = ReadDataFromJson(yourString, XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema);
```

Comment: The problem with this is the xml format won't retain int, bool etc. If you use this method and convert it back to a json string then all your booleans will now be "false" (with quotes) instead of just false (without quotes) and your ints will be "1" instead of 1.

Comment: @nickvans I update my answer to support XML read options that can infer types -HTH ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function convertJsonStringToDataSet(jsonString As String) As DataSet
    Dim xd As New XmlDocument()
    jsonString = "{ ""rootNode"": {" + jsonString.Trim().TrimStart("{"c).TrimEnd("}"c) + "} }"
    xd = DirectCast(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonString), XmlDocument
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ds.ReadXml(New XmlNodeReader(xd))
    Return ds
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you follow Nick's suggestion... and perhaps your web services should modified because I saw similar property on each Table and Table1 and property inside...

1. Create class using json2csharp.com and I got this

   ```
   public class Table
   {
       public string DisplayVoucherNumber { get; set; }
       public string ActualDate { get; set; }
       public string AccountName { get; set; }
       public string NetWeight { get; set; }
       public string Weight { get; set; }
       public string Pcs { get; set; }
       public string Difference { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Deserialize json string using
   `List<Table> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Table>>(jsonstring);`
3. You can access that list object to put on your DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **class** for your deserialized data.
2. **Use**:

   ```
   YourClass yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(jsonStr);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
string json = @"{
  'Table1': [
    {
      'id': 0,
      'item': 'item 0'
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'item': 'item 1'
    }
  ]
}";

DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);

DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["Table1"];
```

Serialize json : [Link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm)