# Deserializing dynamically a json file were some cells are empty and getting an invalid array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, wpf, dynamic

When I deserialize a json dynamically i get an array with fewer columns on some rows.

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(filePath))
{
    dynamic words = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(file.ReadToEnd(), new ExpandoObject());
    DataTable dt = ToDataTable(words.wordlist.item);

    return dt;
}

public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
    {
        var data = items.ToArray();
        if (data.Count() == 0) return null;

        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var key in ((IDictionary<string, object>)data[0]).Keys)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(key);
        }
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(((IDictionary<string, object>)d).Values.ToArray());
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

I understand why it does this but I can't find any way to fix it.

Comment: Manged to solve it using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34287982/4857852)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Comment: Got error 'Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Comment: Can you post your json? Or perhaps a fragment of the problematic portion?

Comment: Do you have control over how the json is produced?

Comment: no because these are already generated json files that have differences and I want to display the data dynamically on a DataGrid. I will post some of the json.

Comment: stack overflow wont let me post more code but I found that the json on some rows it has the missing column and on some others it doesn't.