# inserting data from REST webservice into database using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, json, web-services, ssis, script-task

I want to pull `JSON` data from REST webservice and insert it into SQL Server database using Script task in SQL Server Integration Services. Anyone knows a step by step tutorials or where to start looking to achieve this task. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert JSON to DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)

Comment: I voted to close this question as JSON-to-datatable is basically solved with the JSON.NET library.