# Deserialize JSON object to Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, json, c#-4.0

IDE: Visual Studio 2010
Platform: C#

I am trying to convert the JSON object which consist of data in two different tables into Data table. Here is the code I have written:

```
JavaScriptSerializer objJSSWW = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var lastBattingDetailsWW = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpDetails>(JsonBattingWW);


public class EmpDetails
{
    public List<List<object>> Table { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> Table1 { get; set; }
}
```

I want these two tables to be stored in DataTable. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Why am i down voted so much ?

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get?

Comment: I tried this

 DataTable dtValue = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonBattingWW, (typeof(DataTable)));

Got this error:

Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.

Comment: Again, one more down vote, this is unbelievable ...

Comment: don't understand it neither... you get an upvote from me.

Comment: You're downvoted because you've not searched. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable/11982180#11982180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to give you some (at least pseudo-)code.
Assuming you have a fixed length of your 'List's. For this example I'm assuming your List contains 3 elements.

```
DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
dataTable1.Columns.Add("col1");
dataTable1.Columns.Add("col2");
dataTable1.Columns.Add("col3");
foreach (var row in EmpDetails.Table)
{
    dataTable1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
}

DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable();
dataTable2.Columns.Add("col1");
dataTable2.Columns.Add("col2");
dataTable2.Columns.Add("col3");
foreach (var row in EmpDetails.Table1)
{
    dataTable2.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
}
```

If you have 2 tables with the same columns you can simply merge them:

```
dataTable1.Merge(dataTable2);
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer , but this will take a lot of time if there are some lakhs of records. I am looking for some way to deserialize it in one go instead of looping through all the records...

Comment: deserialization also does loop through it... somehow.