# Converting JSON string to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datatable, json-deserialization

I know this kind of question has been asked before but I cannot seem to find anything that is working.

I am trying to convert a JSON string to a DataTable, or any other form that I can work with on C#.

Here is an example of the JSON file I receive:

```
{ "DatabaseName" : {"Employees": [{"Full-Name":"John Smith","Address":["123 Main St", "Apt 202"],"City":"NYC"}]}}
```

I have tried different things, but I either get an empty DataTable, or many different errors.

```
Object jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(Response.Content);
DataTable dsResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jObject.ToString());
```

Gives me:

> Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have used JSON 2 C# to create a class as well, and trying to convert it using

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employees>(Response.Content);
```

However the classes do not allow me to create a variable `public string Full-Name` since I cannot use a - when creating a variable.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert JSON to DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)

Comment: You shouldn't convert it to a DataTable, you should convert it to a model object (a plain class). To figure out what the class structure should be, I like [http://json2csharp.com/](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: When doing that, I get the following error:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProDataSet]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type

Comment: @user130622 You have to make sure you deserialize to the correct class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JSON is invalid, use this to check: http://jsonlint.com/

should be something like

```
{
    "DatabaseName": "Employees",
    "Rows": [
        {
            "FullName": "John Smith",
            "Address": [
                "123 Main St",
                "Apt 202"
            ],
            "City": "NYC"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Fixed the JSON string on this example. I was missed an opening bracket when typing the json string on here. But the string is a valid json.

Comment: you could deserialize this to a Dictionary<string,Object>

Comment: On the converted class from json2csharp you can decorate the fullname property with this attribute:  `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="Full-Name")]
public string FullName { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json 2 C#](http://json2csharp.com/#) to create your class and like @Plutonix said look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable) for the Data Table.

Comment: I expanded the question. Json 2 C# gives me __invalid name for most of the public variables created in the class, as they contain a dash. Is there a trick to this?

Comment: Correct your json look at @NeonBoxx answer

Comment: The json string I receive from the service is correct, but forgot to put an opening bracket when writing the question.

Comment: So now that you have your class you can start populate your DataTable