# I have a JSON file and i want to display its data in a table

Tags: json, vb.net

But i cant understand how to use JSON Parser.
Sample codes please using my JSON Data.
Thanks in advance..

```
{"androidDisplayName":"BOQUEO RUFINO RO","androidDescription":"05 17 3 010 99 69","geopoint_hh_ind":"1","geopoint_hh":{"latitude":"13.320313333333335","longitude":"123.66615833333331","altitude":"291.9","accuracy":"9.3"},"regn":"05","prov":"05","mun":"17","zone":"3","brgy":"010","purok":"99","street":"none","hnum":"0","hcn":"69","respondent":"BOQUEO RUFINO","int_date":"2014-07-02","start_time":"12:55","interviewer":"RONALD BONAFUS","house_type":"1","house_type_o":"","nbr":1,"roof":"2","wall":"2","nofw":0,"nnucfam":3,"hpregind":"2","uniparind":"2","disableind":"2","phsize":8,"hpq_mem":[{"memno":"1404302501330","msname":"BOQUEO","mfname":"RUFINO","mmname":"BUESA","nucfam":"1","reln":"1","reln_o":"","sex":"1","birth_date":"1948-04-22","age":66.5160848733744,"age_yr":66,"birth_reg":"1","civstat":"3","ethgrp":"37","ethgrp_o":"","ofw":null,"mlenresid":"1","country_resid":"","country_resid_o":"","prov_resid_code":"","mun_resid_code":"","brgy_resid_code":"","mun_resid_txt":"","brgy_resid_txt":"","educind":"2","gradel":"","sch_type":"","gradel_calc":499,"ynotsch":"","ynotsch_o":"","educal":"100","psced7":"","course_o":"","literind":"1","regvotind":"1","voted_last_election":"1","jobind":"1","entrepind":null,"njob":1,"occup":"VEGETABLE FARMER","psoc4":"6114","indust":"AGRICULTURE","psic4":"0118","jstatus":"1","work_ddhrs":6,"work_wkhrs":36,"fadd_work_hrs":"2","fxtra_wrk":"2","workcl":"2","fjob":null,"first_fjob":null,"jsearch_meth":"","jsearch_meth_o":"","wks_fjob":0,"ynotlookjob":"","ynotlookjob_o":"","lastlookjob":"","joppind":null,"wtwind":null,"wagcshm":0,"wagkndm":0,"sss_ind":"4","pregind":null,"solo_parent":"1","pwd_ind":null,"pwd_type":"","pwd_type_o":"","pwd_id":null,"scid_ind":"1","mcrimeind":"2","mtheftind":null,"mrapeind":null,"minjurind":null,"mcarnapind":null,"mcattrustlind":null,"mocrimind":null,"mocrim":"","mtheftloc":null,"mrapeloc":null,"minjurloc":null,"mcarnaploc":null,"mcattrustlloc":null,"mocrimloc":null,"mnutind":"","mnutind_date":""},{"memno":"1404302501331","msname":"BOQUEO","mfname":"EVELYN","mmname":"CA\u00d1ETA","nucfam":"1","reln":"2","reln_o":"","sex":"2","birth_date":"1955-05-30","age":59.41409993155373,"age_yr":59,"birth_reg":"1","civstat":"2","ethgrp":"37","ethgrp_o":"","ofw":null,"mlenresid":"1","country_resid":"","country_resid_o":"","prov_resid_code":"","mun_resid_code":"","brgy_resid_code":"","mun_resid_txt":"","brgy_resid_txt":"","educind":"2","gradel":"","sch_type":"","gradel_calc":499,"ynotsch":"","ynotsch_o":"","educal":"100","psced7":"","course_o":"","literind":"1","regvotind":"1","voted_last_election":"1","jobind":"2","entrepind":"2","njob":0,"occup":"","psoc4":"","indust":"","psic4":"","jstatus":"","work_ddhrs":0,"work_wkhrs":0,"fadd_work_hrs":null,"fxtra_wrk":null,"workcl":"","fjob":"2","first_fjob":null,"jsearch_meth":"","jsearch_meth_o":"","wks_fjob":0,"ynotlookjob":"7","ynotlookjob_o":"","lastlookjob":"3","joppind":"2","wtwind":"2","wagcshm":0,"wagkndm":0,"sss_ind":"4","pregind":null,"solo_parent":null,"pwd_ind":null,"pwd_type":"","pwd_type_o":"","pwd_id":null,"scid_ind":null,"mcrimeind":"2","mtheftind":null,"mrapeind":null,"minjurind":null,"mcarnapind":null,"mcattrustlind":null,"mocrimind":null,"mocrim":"","mtheftloc":null,"mrapeloc":null,"minjurloc":null,"mcarnaploc":null,"mcattrustlloc":null,"mocrimloc":null,"mnutind":"","mnutind_date":""},{"memno":"1404302501332","msname":"BOQUEO","mfname":"RONALD","mmname":"CA\u00d1ETA","nucfam":"1","reln":"3","reln_o":"","sex":"1","birth_date":"1987-02-08","age":27.718001368925393,"age_yr":27,"birth_reg":"1","civstat":"1","ethgrp":"37","ethgrp_o":"","ofw":null,"mlenresid":"1","country_resid":"","country_resid_o":"","prov_resid_code":"","mun_resid_code":"","brgy_resid_code":"","mun_resid_txt":"","brgy_resid_txt":"","educind":"2","gradel":"","sch_type":"","gradel_calc":499,"ynotsch":"","ynotsch_o":"","educal":"200","psced7":"","course_o":"","literind":"1","regvotind":"1","voted_last_election":"1","jobind":"1","entrepind":null,"njob":1,"occup":"CARETAKER/FISHPOND/PRIVATE","psoc4":"9213","indust":"AQUACULTURE","psic4":"0312","jstatus":"1","work_ddhrs":8,"work_wkhrs":48,"fadd_work_hrs":"2","fxtra_wrk":"2","workcl":"2","fjob":null,"first_fjob":null,"jsearch_meth":"","jsearch_meth_o":"","wks_fjob":0,"ynotlookjob":"","ynotlookjob_o":"","lastlookjob":"","joppind":null,"wtwind":null,"wagcshm":36000,"wagkndm":0,"sss_ind":"4","pregind":null,"solo_parent":"2","pwd_ind":null,"pwd_type":"","pwd_type_o":"","pwd_id":null,"scid_ind":null,"mcrimeind":"2","mtheftind":null,"mrapeind":null,"minjurind":null,"mcarnapind":null,"mcattrustlind":null,"mocrimind":null,"mocrim":"","mtheftloc":null,"mrapeloc":null,"minjurloc":null,"mcarnaploc":null,"mcattrustlloc":null,"mocrimloc":null,"mnutind":"","mnutind_date":""},{"memno":"1404302501333","msname":"BOQUEO","mfname":"DANTE","mmname":"CA\u00d1ETA","nucfam":"1","reln":"3","reln_o":"","sex":"1","birth_date":"1989-07-03","age":25.319758156513803,"age_yr":25,"birth_reg":"1","civstat":"1","ethgrp":"37","ethgrp_o":"","ofw":null,"mlenresid":"1","country_resid":"","country_resid_o":"","prov_resid_code":"","mun_resid_code":"","brgy_resid_code":"","mun_resid_txt":"","brgy_resid_txt":"","educind":"2","gradel":"","sch_type":"","gradel_calc":499,"ynotsch":"","ynotsch_o":"","educal":"41","psced7":"","course_o":"","literind":"1","regvotind":"1","voted_last_election":"1","jobind":"2","entrepind":"2","njob":0,"occup":"","psoc4":"","indust":"","psic4":"","jstatus":"","work_ddhrs":0,"work_wkhrs":0,"fadd_work_hrs":null,"fxtra_wrk":null,"workcl":"","fjob":"1","first_fjob":"1","jsearch_meth":"4","jsearch_meth_o":"","wks_fjob":4,"ynotlookjob":"","ynotlookjob_o":"","lastlookjob":"","joppind":"1","wtwind":"1","wagcshm":0,"wagkndm":0,"sss_ind":"4","pregind":null,"solo_parent":"2","pwd_ind":null,"pwd_type":"","pwd_type_o":"","pwd_id":null,"scid_ind":null,"mcrimeind":"2","mtheftind":null,"mrapeind":null,"minjurind":null,"mcarnapind":null,"mcattrustlind":null,"mocrimind":null,"mocrim":"","mtheftloc":null,"mrapeloc":null,"minjurloc":null,"mcarnaploc":null,"mcattrustlloc":null,"mocrimloc":null,"mnutind":"","mnutind_date":""},{"memno":"1404302501334","msname":"RIVERA","mfname":"MARLYN","mmname":"BOQUEO","nucfam":"2","reln":"3","reln_o":"","sex":"2","birth_date":"1979-02-14","age":35.7015742642026,"age_yr":35,"birth_reg":"1","civstat":"3","ethgrp":"37","ethgrp_o":"","ofw":null,"mlenresid":"1","country_resid":"","country_resid_o":"","prov_resid_code":"","mun_resid_code":"","brgy_resid_code":"","mun_resid_txt":"","brgy_resid_txt":"","educind":"2","gradel":"","sch_type":"","gradel_calc":499,"ynotsch":"","ynotsch_o":"","educal":"100","psced7":"","course_o":"","literind":"1","regvotind":"1","voted_last_election":"1","jobind":"2","entrepind":"2","njob":0,"occup":"","psoc4":"","indust":"","psic4":"","jstatus":"","work_ddhrs":0,"work_wkhrs":0,"fadd_work_hrs":null,"fxtra_wrk":null,"workcl":"","fjob":"1","first_fjob":"2","jsearch_meth":"4","jsearch_meth_o":"","wks_fjob":4,"ynotlookjob":"","ynotlookjob_o":"","lastlookjob":"","joppind":"1","wtwind":"1","wagcshm":0,"wagkndm":0,"sss_ind":"4","pregind":null,"solo_parent":"2","pwd_ind":null,"pwd_type":"","pwd_type_o":"","pwd_id":null,"scid_ind":null,"mcrimeind":"2","mtheftind":null,"mrapeind":null,"minjurind":null,"mcarnapind":null,"mcattrustlind":null,"mocrimind":null,"mocrim":"","mtheftloc":null,"mrapeloc":null,"minjurloc":null,"mcarnaploc":null,"mcattrustlloc":null,"mocrimloc":null,"mnutind":"","mnutind_date":""},{"memno":"1404302501335","msname":"BOQUEO","mfname":"BERNARD","mmname":"CA\u00d1ETA","nucfam":"3","reln":"3","reln_o":"","sex":"1","birth_date":"1984-06-08","age":30.38740588637919,"age_yr":30,"birth_reg":"1","civstat":"2","ethgrp":"37","ethgrp_o":"","ofw":null,"mlenresid":"1","country_resid":"","country_resid_o":"","prov_resid_code":"","mun_resid_code":"","brgy_resid_code":"","mun_resid_txt":"","brgy_resid_txt":"","educind":"2","gradel":"","sch_type":"","gradel_calc":499,"ynotsch":"","ynotsch_o":"","educal":"100","psced7":"","course_o":"","literind":"1","regvotind":"1","voted_last_election":"1","jobind":"1","entrepind":null,"njob":1,"occup":"DRIVER HABAL HABAL","psoc4":"8321","indust":"TRANSPORTATION AND STORAGE","psic4":"4932","jstatus":"1","work_ddhrs":10,"work_wkhrs":60,"fadd_work_hrs":"2","fxtra_wrk":"2","workcl":"4","fjob":null,"first_fjob":null,"jsearch_meth":"","jsearch_meth_o":"","wks_fjob":0,"ynotlookjob":"","ynotlookjob_o":"","lastlookjob":"","joppind":null,"wtwind":null,"wagcshm":100800,"wagkndm":0,"sss_ind":"4","pregind":null,"solo_parent":null,"pwd_ind":null,"pwd_type":"","pwd_type_o":"","pwd_id":null,"scid_ind":null,"mcrimeind":"2","mtheftind":null,"mrapeind":null,"minjurind":null,"mcarnapind":null,"mcattrustlind":null,"mocrimind":null,"mocrim":"","mtheftloc":null,"mrapeloc":null,"minjurloc":null,"mcarnaploc":null,"mcattrustlloc":null,"mocrimloc":null,"mnutind":"","mnutind_date":""},{"memno":"1404302501336","msname":"BOQUEO","mfname":"JOAN","mmname":"RAGODON","nucfam":"3","reln":"4","reln_o":"","sex":"2","birth_date":"1994-07-01","age":20.32580424366872,"age_yr":20,"birth_reg":"1","civstat":"2","ethgrp":"37","ethgrp_o":"","ofw":null,"mlenresid":"1","country_resid":"","country_resid_o":"","prov_resid_code":"","mun_resid_code":"","brgy_resid_code":"","mun_resid_txt":"","brgy_resid_txt":"","educind":"2","gradel":"","sch_type":"","gradel_calc":499,"ynotsch":"7","ynotsch_o":"","educal":"100","psced7":"","course_o":"","literind":"1","regvotind":"1","voted_last_election":"1","jobind":"2","entrepind":"2","njob":0,"occup":"","psoc4":"","indust":"","psic4":"","jstatus":"","work_ddhrs":0,"work_wkhrs":0,"fadd_work_hrs":null,"fxtra_wrk":null,"workcl":"","fjob":"2","first_fjob":null,"jsearch_meth":"","jsearch_meth_o":"","wks_fjob":0,"ynotlookjob":"7","ynotlookjob_o":"","lastlookjob":"3","joppind":"2","wtwind":"2","wagcshm":0,"wagkndm":0,"sss_ind":"4","pregind":null,"solo_parent":null,"pwd_ind":null,"pwd_type":"","pwd_type_o":"","pwd_id":null,"scid_ind":null,"mcrimeind":"2","mtheftind":null,"mrapeind":null,"minjurind":null,"mcarnapind":null,"mcattrustlind":null,"mocrimind":null,"mocrim":"","mtheftloc":null,"mrapeloc":null,"minjurloc":null,"mcarnaploc":null,"mcattrustlloc":null,"mocrimloc":null,"mnutind":"","mnutind_date":""},{"memno":"1404302501337","msname":"BOQUEO","mfname":"ROCHELL","mmname":"RAGODON","nucfam":"3","reln":"5","reln_o":"","sex":"2","birth_date":"2014-06-07","age":0.3915126625598905,"age_yr":0,"birth_reg":"1","civstat":"1","ethgrp":"37","ethgrp_o":"","ofw":null,"mlenresid":null,"country_resid":"","country_resid_o":"","prov_resid_code":"","mun_resid_code":"","brgy_resid_code":"","mun_resid_txt":"","brgy_resid_txt":"","educind":null,"gradel":"","sch_type":"","gradel_calc":499,"ynotsch":"","ynotsch_o":"","educal":"","psced7":"","course_o":"","literind":null,"regvotind":null,"voted_last_election":null,"jobind":null,"entrepind":null,"njob":0,"occup":"","psoc4":"","indust":"","psic4":"","jstatus":"","work_ddhrs":0,"work_wkhrs":0,"fadd_work_hrs":null,"fxtra_wrk":null,"workcl":"","fjob":null,"first_fjob":null,"jsearch_meth":"","jsearch_meth_o":"","wks_fjob":0,"ynotlookjob":"","ynotlookjob_o":"","lastlookjob":"","joppind":null,"wtwind":null,"wagcshm":0,"wagkndm":0,"sss_ind":null,"pregind":null,"solo_parent":null,"pwd_ind":null,"pwd_type":"","pwd_type_o":"","pwd_id":null,"scid_ind":null,"mcrimeind":"2","mtheftind":null,"mrapeind":null,"minjurind":null,"mcarnapind":null,"mcattrustlind":null,"mocrimind":null,"mocrim":"","mtheftloc":null,"mrapeloc":null,"minjurloc":null,"mcarnaploc":null,"mcattrustlloc":null,"mocrimloc":null,"mnutind":"2","mnutind_date":"2014-07-01"}],"water":"2","water_o":"","water_dist":20,"toil":"5","toil_o":"","tenur":"1","tenur_o":"","imprnt":600,"welec":"1","elec_company":"1","elec_generator":"2","elec_solar":"2","elec_battery":"2","elec_source_o":"2","elec_source_o_lb":"","radio":1,"radio_nwacq":0,"tv":0,"tv_nwacq":0,"vplayer":0,"vplayer_nwacq":0,"stereo":0,"stereo_nwacq":0,"karaoke":0,"karaoke_nwacq":0,"ref":0,"ref_nwacq":0,"efan":0,"efan_nwacq":0,"iron":0,"iron_nwacq":0,"stove":0,"stove_nwacq":0,"wmach":0,"wmach_nwacq":0,"microw":0,"microw_nwacq":0,"computer":0,"computer_nwacq":0,"internet":0,"internet_nwacq":0,"celfone":1,"celfone_nwacq":0,"telefone":0,"telefone_nwacq":0,"airc":0,"airc_nwacq":0,"sewmach":0,"sewmach_nwacq":0,"car":0,"car_nwacq":0,"motor":0,"motor_nwacq":0,"landagri":1,"landagri_nwacq":0,"landres":0,"landres_nwacq":0,"landcomm":0,"landcomm_nwacq":0,"sofa":0,"sofa_nwacq":0,"dineset":0,"dineset_nwacq":0,"own_other":0,"own_other_o":"","own_other_nwacq":0,"insur_house":"2","insur_house_src":"","insur_house_src_o":"","insur_motor":"2","insur_motor_src":"","insur_motor_src_o":"","insur_appliance":"2","insur_appliance_src":"","insur_appliance_src_o":"","garb_collect":"2","garb_burn":"1","garb_comp":"2","garb_recycl":"2","garb_wsegr":"2","garb_cpit":"2","garb_opit":"2","garb_river":"2","garb_mgt_o":"2","garb_mgt_o_lb":"","garb_collector":"","garb_collector_o":"","freq_garb_coll":"","freq_garb_coll_o":"","cropind":"1","cropincsh":2000,"cropinknd":1000,"poultind":"2","pouincsh":0,"pouinknd":0,"fishind":"2","fishincsh":0,"fishinknd":0,"forind":"2","forincsh":0,"forinknd":0,"salind":"2","salincsh":0,"salinknd":0,"manind":"2","manincsh":0,"maninknd":0,"servind":"2","servincsh":0,"servinknd":0,"trnind":"2","trnincsh":0,"trninknd":0,"minind":"2","minincsh":0,"mininknd":0,"cnsind":"2","cnsincsh":0,"cnsinknd":0,"eothind":"2","eoincsh":0,"eoinknd":0,"etotcsh":2000,"etotknd":1000,"wagcsh":136800,"wagknd":0,"agscsh":0,"agsknd":0,"ofwcsh":0,"ofwknd":0,"supfcsh":0,"supfknd":0,"suprcsh":0,"suprknd":0,"rentvcsh":0,"rentvknd":0,"intrcsh":0,"intrknd":0,"pencsh":0,"penknd":0,"divcsh":0,"divknd":0,"othscsh":0,"othsknd":0,"othstotcsh":0,"othstotknd":0,"imprnttot":7200,"totincsh":138800,"totinknd":8200,"totin":147000,"nalp":0,"hpq_alp":[],"ncrop":2,"hpq_crop":[{"crop_line":"1404302501354","croptype":"4","croptype_o":"SQUASH,EGGPLANT","crop_vol":3},{"crop_line":"1404302501355","croptype":"4","croptype_o":"KAMOTE,CASSAVA","crop_vol":5}],"agriequip1":"2","agriequip1_nown":0,"agriequip2":"1","agriequip2_nown":1,"agriequip3":"2","agriequip3_nown":0,"agriequip4":"2","agriequip4_nown":0,"agriequip5":"2","agriequip5_nown":0,"agriequip6":"2","agriequip6_nown":0,"agriequip7":"2","agriequip7_nown":0,"agriequip8":"2","agriequip8_nown":0,"agriequip9":"2","agriequip9_nown":0,"agriequip10":"2","agriequip10_nown":0,"agriequip11":"2","agriequip11_nown":0,"agriequip12":"2","agriequip12_nown":0,"agriequip13":"2","agriequip13_nown":0,"agriequip14":"2","agriequip14_nown":0,"agriequip15":"2","agriequip15_nown":0,"agriequip16":"2","agriequip16_nown":0,"agriequip17":"2","agriequip17_nown":0,"agriequip18":"2","agriequip18_nown":0,"agriequip18_o":"","live_a_hog":null,"live_a_hog_vol":0,"live_a_goat":null,"live_a_goat_vol":0,"live_a_carabao":null,"live_a_carabao_vol":0,"live_a_cow":null,"live_a_cow_vol":0,"live_a_chicken":null,"live_a_chicken_vol":0,"live_a_duck":null,"live_a_duck_vol":0,"live_a_others":null,"live_a_others_o":"","live_a_others_vol":0,"meat_hog":null,"meat_hog_vol":0,"meat_goat":null,"meat_goat_vol":0,"meat_carabao":null,"meat_carabao_vol":0,"meat_cow":null,"meat_cow_vol":0,"meat_chicken":null,"meat_chicken_vol":0,"meat_duck":null,"meat_duck_vol":0,"meat_others":null,"meat_others_o":"","meat_others_vol":0,"milk_goat":null,"milk_goat_vol":0,"milk_carabao":null,"milk_carabao_vol":0,"milk_cow":null,"milk_cow_vol":0,"milk_others":null,"milk_others_o":"","milk_others_vol":0,"egg_chicken":null,"egg_chicken_vol":0,"egg_duck":null,"egg_duck_vol":0,"egg_others":null,"egg_others_o":"","egg_others_vol":0,"oani_ind":null,"oani_txt":"","oani_hog":null,"oani_hog_vol":0,"oani_goat":null,"oani_goat_vol":0,"oani_carabao":null,"oani_carabao_vol":0,"oani_cow":null,"oani_cow_vol":0,"oani_chicken":null,"oani_chicken_vol":0,"oani_duck":null,"oani_duck_vol":0,"oani_others":null,"oani_others_o":"","oani_others_vol":0,"catch_fish":null,"cul_fish":null,"catch_fish_loc":null,"boat1":null,"boat1_own":null,"boat2":null,"boat2_own":null,"boat3":null,"boat3_own":null,"boat4":null,"boat4_own":null,"boat5":null,"boat5_own":null,"naquaequip":0,"hpq_aquaequip":[],"fishpond":null,"fishpen":null,"fishcage":null,"seaweedfarm":null,"oysterfarm":null,"musselfarm":null,"fishtank":null,"hatchery":null,"aquafarm_o":null,"aquafarm_o_txt":"","naquani":0,"hpq_aquani":[],"maxyr_resid":"1","yrs_in_cropind":"1","u_amt_harv":"1","u_low_harv":"2","u_low_harv_o_lb":"","u_chng_scrop":"2","u_chng_scrop_y":"","u_chng_scrop_y_o_lb":"","u_chng_pcrop":"2","u_chng_pcrop_y":"","u_chng_pcrop_y_o_lb":"","irfa_crop":"2","irfa_crop_src":"","irfa_crop_src_o":"","irfa_agriequip":"2","irfa_agriequip_src":"","irfa_agriequip_src_o":"","yrs_in_lstockind":null,"u_amt_lve":null,"u_low_lve":"","u_low_lve_o_lb":"","irfa_anim":null,"irfa_anim_src":"","irfa_anim_src_o":"","yrs_in_fishind":null,"u_amt_fish":null,"u_low_fish":"","u_low_fish_o_lb":"","irfa_fish":null,"irfa_fish_src":"","irfa_fish_src_o":"","temp_humid":"1","elec_loss":"1","sea_level":"4","water_supply":"3","low_wsupp":"","low_wsupp_o_lb":"","flood_freq":"3","flood_duration":0,"flood_duration_12":0,"drought":"1","drought_duration":"1","evac_mveout":"2","evac_ymveout":"","evac_ymveout_o":"","evac_trans":"1","evac_cntr":"4","evac_cntr_o_lb":"","calam1":"1","calam1_hwmny":1,"calam1_aid":"2","calam1_hus_aid":"","calam1_hus_aid_o":"","calam2":"2","calam2_hwmny":0,"calam2_aid":null,"calam2_hus_aid":"","calam2_hus_aid_o":"","calam3":"2","calam3_hwmny":0,"calam3_aid":null,"calam3_hus_aid":"","calam3_hus_aid_o":"","calam4":"2","calam4_hwmny":0,"calam4_aid":null,"calam4_hus_aid":"","calam4_hus_aid_o":"","calam5":"2","calam5_hwmny":0,"calam5_aid":null,"calam5_hus_aid":"","calam5_hus_aid_o":"","calam6":"2","calam6_hwmny":0,"calam6_aid":null,"calam6_hus_aid":"","calam6_hus_aid_o":"","calam7":"2","calam7_hwmny":0,"calam7_aid":null,"calam7_hus_aid":"","calam7_hus_aid_o":"","calam8":"2","calam8_hwmny":0,"calam8_aid":null,"calam8_hus_aid":"","calam8_hus_aid_o":"","calam9":"2","calam9_hwmny":0,"calam9_aid":null,"calam9_hus_aid":"","calam9_hus_aid_o":"","calam10":"2","calam10_hwmny":0,"calam10_aid":null,"calam10_hus_aid":"","calam10_hus_aid_o":"","calam11":"2","calam11_o":"","calam11_hwmny":0,"calam11_aid":null,"calam11_hus_aid":"","calam11_hus_aid_o":"","disas_prep":"2","dp_kit1":null,"dp_kit1_xpiry":0,"dp_kit2":null,"dp_kit2_xpiry":0,"dp_kit3":null,"dp_kit4":null,"dp_kit5":null,"dp_kit6":null,"dp_kit7":null,"dp_kit8":null,"dp_kit9":null,"dp_kit10":null,"dp_kit11":null,"dp_kit12":null,"dp_kit13":null,"dp_kit13_o":"","dp_kit13_xpiry":0,"fshort":"2","fsmonth_1":"","fsdays_1":0,"fsmonth_2":"","fsdays_2":0,"fsmonth_3":"","fsdays_3":0,"prevmind":"2","ndeath":0,"hpq_death":[],"prog_slp":"2","prog_slp_nmem":0,"hpq_slp_mem":[],"prog_slp_impl":"","prog_slp_impl_o":"","prog_fudforsch":"2","prog_fudforsch_nmem":0,"hpq_fudforsch_mem":[],"prog_fudforsch_impl":"","prog_fudforsch_impl_o":"","prog_fudforwrk":"2","prog_fudforwrk_nmem":0,"hpq_fudforwrk_mem":[],"prog_fudforwrk_impl":"","prog_fudforwrk_impl_o":"","prog_cshforwrk":"2","prog_cshforwrk_nmem":0,"hpq_cshforwrk_mem":[],"prog_cshforwrk_impl":"","prog_cshforwrk_impl_o":"","prog_spisc":"2","prog_spisc_nmem":0,"hpq_spisc_mem":[],"prog_spisc_impl":"","prog_spisc_impl_o":"","prog_cct":"2","prog_cct_nmem":0,"hpq_cct_mem":[],"prog_cct_impl":"","prog_cct_impl_o":"","prog_arcdp":"2","prog_arcdp_nmem":0,"hpq_arcdp_mem":[],"prog_arcdp_impl":"","prog_arcdp_impl_o":"","prog_cbep":"2","prog_cbep_nmem":0,"hpq_cbep_mem":[],"prog_cbep_impl":"","prog_cbep_impl_o":"","prog_phiheal_ofw":"2","prog_phiheal_ofw_nmem":0,"hpq_phiheal_ofw_mem":[],"prog_phiheal_empl":"2","prog_phiheal_empl_nmem":0,"hpq_phiheal_empl_mem":[],"prog_phiheal_indiv":"2","prog_phiheal_indiv_nmem":0,"hpq_phiheal_indiv_mem":[],"prog_phiheal_spon":"2","prog_phiheal_spon_nmem":0,"hpq_phiheal_spon_mem":[],"prog_phiheal_spon_impl":"","prog_phiheal_spon_impl_o":"","prog_phiheal_life":"2","prog_phiheal_life_nmem":0,"hpq_phiheal_life_mem":[],"nprog":1,"hpq_prog":[{"prog_line":"1404302501357","progtype":"22","progname":"POVERTY ALLEVIATION PROGRAM","prognmem":1,"hpq_prog_mem":[{"hpq_prog_mem_refno":"1404302501330"}],"progimplementor":"3","progimplementor_o":""}],"end_time":"12:54","supervisor":"MARY GRACE CASAUL"}
```

My code is this.. (I just got this from an answer in this site but it only reads the data after "hpq_mem", what i want to do is to read all the datas and place it to a table which the headers are the variables in my JSON Data..

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim json As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim data = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(json)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<table>" & vbLf & "<thead>" & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbLf)
    For Each key As String In data("hpq_mem")(0).Keys
        sb.AppendFormat("<th>{0}</th>" & vbLf, key)
    Next
    sb.Append("</tr>" & vbLf & "</thead>" & vbLf & "<tbody>" & vbLf)
    For Each item As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In data("hpq_mem")
        sb.Append("<tr>" & vbLf)
        For Each val As String In item.Values
            sb.AppendFormat("      <td>{0}</td>" & vbLf, val)
        Next
    Next
         sb.Append("</tr>" & vbLf & "</tbody>" & vbLf & "</table>")
         Dim myTable As String = sb.ToString()
         WebBrowser1.DocumentText = myTable
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: this thread may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable

Comment: they all talk about c#, i'm working on vb.. but thanks i again..

Comment: i suggest that as a reference, not as answer

Comment: yeah.. i got it.. is it possible to have an array inside an array?? i think its the problem on my JSON Data..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. This assume you only need data from the `hpq_mem` property.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(TextBox1.Text)

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<table>" & vbLf & "<thead>" & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbLf)

    Dim firstIterate = True
    For Each hpqMemObject As JObject In myJsonObject("hpq_mem")
        If firstIterate Then
            For Each keyPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, JToken) In hpqMemObject
                sb.AppendFormat("<th>{0}</th>" & vbLf, keyPair.Key)
            Next
            sb.Append("</tr>" & vbLf & "</thead>" & vbLf & "<tbody>" & vbLf)
            firstIterate = False
        End If
        sb.Append("<tr>" & vbLf)
        For Each keyPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, JToken) In hpqMemObject
            sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>" & vbLf, keyPair.Value)
        Next
    Next
    sb.Append("</tr>" & vbLf & "</tbody>" & vbLf & "</table>")

    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = sb.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code sample.. i was thinking if i can include all the datas fron start to end. am I right that it reads when the data is enclosed with "[" and "]".. so is there a way to read the other variables??

Comment: if you are to deserialize everything, you have to create classes for each object. When part of the Json is within the square bracket,"[]" it's refer to an array, or maybe you can call it a list of object. [understand more about Json](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm). And yes, it's possible to read all the variables.

Comment: is this the correct way to create class for each object??  Public Class GeopointHh
        Public Property latitude As String
        Public Property longitude As String
        Public Property altitude As String
        Public Property accuracy As String
    End Class