# JSON to C# a Dynamic List<object> or DataTable

Tags: c#, json

Short version: How can I deserialize a JSON string into a C# list or DataTable without having a defined class to deserialize to?

More explanation: My controller expects a json string which is an array of objects but the properties of the object is unknown. I need to deserialize it into a list and loop through its contents for saving. Sample json strings:

1.

```
[
    {"id":"10","name":"User","add":false,"edit":true,"authorize":true,"view":true},
    {"id":"11","name":"Group","add":true,"edit":false,"authorize":false,"view":true},
    {"id":"12","name":"Permission","add":true,"edit":true,"authorize":true,"view":true}
]
```

2.

```
[
    {"id":"10","name":"User"},
    {"id":"11","name":"Group"},
    {"id":"12","name":"Permission"}
]
```

Comment: May be [`Dynamic`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dynamic) should help you

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object.

Comment: If after deserialize it need loop through its contents for saving, unless you knowing the mapping of the fields like first field = saving field 1, second field =saving field 2, etc. Else I rather define a class to deserialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dynamic jsonObject = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(jsonText);
```

Comment: Beautiful!  This allowed me to convert my web api to partial response by combining this answer with dotarj's solution (https://github.com/dotarj/PartialResponse).  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize your Json and cast it directly to datatable.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282579/4827151