# How to return string value in dataset signature?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
public Dataset getdata(Dataset table) 
{ 
   string JSONString = string.Empty;  
   JSONString = JSONConvert.SerializeObject(table);  
   return JSONString;  
}
```

The above code returning string value but signature is dataset please suggest me how to return string value when signature is dataset.

Comment: you should just return `table` and save us the stress or follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature to a string:

```
public string getdata(Dataset table) {
```

C# is statically typed.  The return type advertised by the method is the type which must be returned.  If your method returns a string, then use `string` as the return type.  The compiler doesn't like methods which lie about what they return.

Comment: but i need to return json data formate to dataset is it possible?

Comment: @veereshasp: In what possible?  In the question you're returning a string, so the return type must be `string`.  It doesn't matter what that string contains, as long as it's a string.  What exactly are you trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: actually i have data in dataset i want to convert it into json formate but i dont want to change signature.

Comment: @veereshasp: Then return the dataset and convert it to JSON elsewhere in the code.  The method either returns a `DataSet` or it returns a `string`.  Wanting to change the return type without wanting to change the return type makes no sense.