# how to convert json response to datatable in c#

Tags: c#, json, datatable

This is my c# post json method .In the result `variable` I got the following json response

```
string token = string.Empty;

string requestUrl = "http://tallentex.com/phpwebservices/feedbackapp/index.php/hostel_service/syncData";
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
        id = "0"
    });
    Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This what i got from json post method request.

> {\"status\":1,\"data\":\"id\":\"1\",\"fno\":\"16078134\",\"hostel_id\":\"12345\",\"attn_no\":\"0010146998\",\"create_date\":\"2017-08-21
>   10:31:02\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"fno\":\"16078134\",\"hostel_id\":\"12345\",\"attn_no\":\"0010146998\",\"create_date\":\"2017-08-21
>   10:31:02\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"fno\":\"16078134\",\"hostel_id\":\"12345\",\"attn_no\":\"0010146998\",\"create_date\":\"2017-08-21
>   10:31:02\"},{\"id\":\"4\",\"fno\":\"16078134\",\"hostel_id\":\"12345\",\"attn_no\":\"0010146998\",\"create_date\":\"2017-08-21
>   10:31:02\"}]}";

I want to convert it into data table like the following table

```
id   fno         attnno     hostelid       createdate
1   16078134    0010146998  12345   2017-08-21 10:31:02
2   16078134    0010146998  12345   2017-08-21 10:31:02
3   16078134    0010146998  12345   2017-08-21 10:31:02
4   16078134    0010146998  12345   2017-08-21 10:31:02
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)

Comment: And your json is not valid

Comment: may be the json was not valid but i got this result from the above method and i want to convert it into datatable