# How do I convert json object to table type so I can incorporate it in the database

Tags: c#, json

May I know how I can convert my JSON data from object to datatable? I need to insert this in my tProducts. Below is my code. I got the Json data from an API.

```
private async void GetHomeItems()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var url = new Uri(IAMSUrl + "/GetProductSRP");
    var content = new StringContent("{CustomerCode: 'test'}");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    //As string
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //As Object
    var objResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SrpResult>(result);
}

public class SrpResult
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool _IsNew { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you show the structure of JSON please

Comment: "ID": 1,
 "_IsNew": false,
 "Items": [
  {
   "ID": 38,
   "Name": "CINEMA SB350",
   "IAMSCode": "asd123",
   "Comment": null,
   "SpecialPrice": null,
   "IsActive": true,
   "SRPAmt": 29990.00,
   "ID_ItemCategory": 9,
   "ItemCategory": "Multimedia",
   "Tag": null,
   "ID_Item": 737,
   "ID_UOM": 4,
   "ProductColor": "BLACK",
   "PrimaryUOM": "PC",
   "IsBigItem": false,
   "StockQty": 0.00,
   "_IsNew": false
  },

Comment: I have post some answers

Answer (score 1):

**1st Solution**

```
private async void GetHomeItems()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var url = new Uri(IAMSUrl + "/GetProductSRP");
    var content = new StringContent("{CustomerCode: 'test'}");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    //As string
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //As Object
    var objResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SrpResult>(result);
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectt<SrpResult>(objResult.toString(), (typeof(DataTable)));
}
```

**2nd Solution**

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1084643/Convert-JSON-To-DataTable-Csharp

Comment: check that link

Comment: kindly explain the stored proc in question

Comment: once I execute this procedure I created. the values from the array of objects will be automatically inserted in my table..

Comment: but you need to first provide the result from calling /GetProductSRP to the stored procedure ... so you  have to **first** anyhow break the JSON into datatable ..even if you later want to to use stored proc

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable

Comment: I am sorry... i dont have visual studio right now... but when I will get it.. I will check & do the modifications required :) & update this answer