# gridview is not showing data properly

Tags: asp.net

while trying to get data from https://blockchain.info/ticker in my grid view, i'm finding the result in single coloumn whether i want it in different coloumn.
i'm showing you my code and please give me a soloution.

```
public void ticker()
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    dynamic result =webClient.DownloadString("https://blockchain.info/ticker");

    GridView1.DataSource = result;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPjgS.jpg]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your results in JSON format so you have to convert in the proper format to display well in GridView.

```
import Newtonsoft.Json 
dynamic result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
webClient.DownloadString("https://blockchain.info/ticker"));
```

I hope it's help you, you can search more about it

thanks