# how to put the data in my api into a table I found in datatables.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, datatables

I use the following js method to get the data from my local database.

```
self.hourlyUsages = ko.observableArray();
var hourlyUsagesURI = 'http://localhost:58734/api/hourlyUsages/DTO/';

function getAllhourlyUsages() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: hourlyUsagesURI + 'Details',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            self.hourlyUsages(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error: " + err.status + " " + err.statusText);
        }
    });

};
```

In my cshtml this is how I display the data.

```
<table id="example" class="display dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>kW/h</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Appliance No.</th>
                <th>Appliance Name</th>
                <th>Date and time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: hourlyUsages">

            <tr role="row" data-bind='if: Id % 2 == 1' class="odd">
                <td class="sorting_1"><strong><span data-bind="text: Id"></span></strong></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: kWh"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: cost"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: appliancesNo"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: appliancesName"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: moment(dateTime).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss')"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" data-bind='if: Id % 2 == 0' class="even">
                <td class="sorting_1"><strong><span data-bind="text: Id"></span></strong></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: kWh"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: cost"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: appliancesNo"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: appliancesName"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: moment(dateTime).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss')"></span></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

with my current method, most of the function that I got from www.datatables.net is not working so I try to look at the web and this is what I found from the website and I want to replace the data in dataSet to the data I have in my api.

```
var dataSet = [
[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
[ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
[ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
[ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
[ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
[ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
[ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
[ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
[ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
[ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
[ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
[ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
[ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
[ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
[ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
[ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
[ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
[ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500" ],
[ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000" ],
[ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ],
[ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000" ],
[ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000" ],
[ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450" ],
[ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
[ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
[ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
[ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
[ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850" ],
[ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
[ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000" ],
[ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400" ],
[ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
[ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
[ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
[ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
[ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" },
        { title: "Extn." },
        { title: "Start date" },
        { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

What should I replace dataSet with if I want to put the data that is store in self.hourlyUsages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)

Comment: DataSet data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);

Comment: @user3165474 When I tried `DataSet data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(self.hourlyUsages);`  the word data got red line and when I tried to search online the DataSet is supposed to be the class name for in js what should put?