# How to efficiently load API results into a DataTable?

Tags: c#

API Response :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "code": 0,
    "msg": "성공하였습니다.",
    "list": [
        {
            "code": "ANT",
            "code_name": "소둔구분",
            "p_code": "",
            "p_code_name": "",
            "code_type": 0,
            "code_level": 0,
            "max_level": 1,
            "description": "GROP : 99  DETL : ANT  SUBS : 00",
            "create_user": "SYSTEM",
            "create_time": "2019-04-24T17:58:58.000+0000",
            "disable_yn": "Y"
        },
        {...}
        ]
}
```

C# API Call :

```
// CodeInfo 초기 데이터 로드
public static DataTable selectAllCodeInfo()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(API_ADDRESS + "/api/codeInfo");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            JObject applyObj = JObject.Parse(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            var applyObj2 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            string success = applyObj["success"].ToString();

            if (success.Equals("True"))
            {
                if (applyObj["list"].ToString() != null)
                {
                    ??????????
                    return dt;
                }  
            } else
            {
                //API 응답 데이터 수신 실패
            }

        }
    } catch(WebException)
    {
        //API 서버 닫혀있을때, 연결이 안될때
        Console.Write("예외");
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //그 외의 Exception
        Console.Write("예외");
        return null;
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I want to efficiently load the above API call return data values into a DataTable.

I've thought of several ways, but haven't found an efficient way yet.

I have tried to use json data as property object.
But it's too cumbersome and inefficient.

Of the Json data above, I want to load only the data contained in the list array as columns and rows in the DataTable.

Is there a good alternative?

Comment: This was answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282579/3744182) to *[Convert JSON to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11981282/3744182)* by [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282579/3744182), Json.NET (which you are already using) currently supports deserializing a list of objects to a `DataTable`.  In the specific JSON provided the list is embedded in a root object property named `"list"`, so you will need to extract it in order to deserialize it.

But since you also ask how to do this in *an efficient way*, you will want to avoid intermediate representations such as `streamReader.ReadToEnd()`, `applyObj` and `applyObj["list"].ToString()`.  To do this, first introduce the following extension method, modeled on [`JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<T>(string value, T anonymousTypeObject)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/a31156e90a14038872f54eb60ff0e9676ca4a0d8/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L735):

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T DeserializeAnonymousType<T>(TextReader textReader, T anonymousTypeObject, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        return (T)JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Deserialize(textReader, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

And now you can do:

```
var root = JsonExtensions.DeserializeAnonymousType(streamReader, 
                                                   new { success = default(bool), list = default(DataTable) });
if (root.success)
{
    var dt = root.list;
    // return the table
}
else
{
    // Handle failure
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MpfLwX).

Answer (score 0):

This code is convert  json to datatable in your case.Json.NET (which you are already using) currently supports deserializing a list of objects to a DataTable.

```
public static DataTable selectAllCodeInfo()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
         var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(API_ADDRESS + "/api/codeInfo");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestParameters))
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(RequestParameters);
                }
            var result = string.Empty;
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(result.list) 

    } catch(WebException)
    {
        //API 서버 닫혀있을때, 연결이 안될때
        Console.Write("예외");
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //그 외의 Exception
        Console.Write("예외");
        return null;
    }
    return dt;
}
```