# Convert JSON to DataTable returns empty result in c#

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I am trying to convert my json data to data table.
Followed all approaches from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable) and also all suggested links all over stackoverflow, tried many ways but still no result.

My method looks like:

```
    public static async Task GetManagements()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Getting managements");

        using var client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", 
        await Token.GetToken());

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(LibvirtUrls.managementUrl);
        HttpContent content = response.Content;

        Console.WriteLine("Response Status Code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var json = Helpers.FormatJson(result);
        Console.WriteLine("json");
        Console.WriteLine(result); // for testing
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-',35));
        Console.WriteLine("formatted");
        Console.WriteLine(json); // for testing
        // I used both result and json (formatted and not formatted one)
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-',35));
        List<NetworkDto> networkList = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NetworkDto>>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("table view");
        var ss = networkList.ToDataTable<NetworkDto>();
        Console.WriteLine(ss);
    }
```

Sample json is after executing method:

```
Getting managements as json
Response Status Code: 200
json
[{"id":1,"netMask":22,"gateway":"10.19.0.1","jenkinsUrl":"http://10.19.0.20:31000","bridge":"br0","ipRange":"10.19.0.1-10.19.3.254"},{"id":11,"netMask":22,"gateway":"10.23.0.1","jenkinsUrl":"http://10.12.3.12:33355","bridge":"br2","ipRange":"10.23.0.4-10.23.0.20"}]
------------------------------------------
formatted
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "netMask":22,
        "gateway":"10.19.0.1",
        "jenkinsUrl":"http://10.19.0.20:31000",
        "bridge":"br0",
        "ipRange":"10.19.0.1-10.19.3.254"
    },
    {
        "id":11,
        "netMask":22,
        "gateway":"10.23.0.1",
        "jenkinsUrl":"http://10.12.3.12:33355",
        "bridge":"br2",
        "ipRange":"10.23.0.4-10.23.0.20"
    }
]
------------------------------------------------
table view
```

Tried also with class:

```
    public class NetworkDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int NetMask { get; set; }
        public string Gateway { get; set; }
        public string JenkinsUrl { get; set; }
        public string Bridge { get; set; }
        public string IpRange { get; set; }
    }
```

Extension method I am using for converting json to data table:

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < props.Count ; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }
        object[] values = new object[props.Count];
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return table;        
    }
```

Comment: Why convert it to a DataTable in the first place? Why not define an class to represent this information, then deserialize to a `List<YourClass>`?

Comment: tried also with List<NetworkDto> but still empty

Comment: Edit your question, include your attempt at deserializing to a `List<NetworkDto>` and show the definition of that class.

Comment: How is NetworkDto defined does an array work?

Comment: Edited question description

Comment: Are you sure, that `Console.WriteLine(dt);` prints the content of the table? I tested with your json and I see the data table filled (in debugger) but not on console.

Comment: I am able print json ugly one and formatted one, but why it is failing with data table no idea

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen I edited my question decription also tried with List of NetworkDto class

Comment: What is the result of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NetworkDto>>(json);`?

Comment: @mason **System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TaikunCLI.NetworkDto]**

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov That's exactly what you want it to be! It works. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deserializing from JSON to a list of custom objects is trivial:

```
List<NetworkDto> networkList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NetworkDto>>(json);
```

And that's it! Now your `networkList` variable is a list of NetworkDto objects. You can write them all out to the console if you want to verify they're in there:

```
foreach(var network in networkList)
(
    Console.WriteLine($"Network Id {network.Id}");
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code:

```
        static void Main() {
        string json = "[{\"id\":1,\"netMask\":22,\"gateway\":\"10.19.0.1\",\"jenkinsUrl\":\"http://10.19.0.20:31000\",\"bridge\":\"br0\",\"ipRange\":\"10.19.0.1-10.19.3.254\"},{\"id\":11,\"netMask\":22,\"gateway\":\"10.23.0.1\",\"jenkinsUrl\":\"http://10.12.3.12:33355\",\"bridge\":\"br2\",\"ipRange\":\"10.23.0.4-10.23.0.20\"}]";

        System.Data.DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(System.Data.DataTable)));
        Console.WriteLine(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
            Console.Write(dt.Columns[i] + " | ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
                Console.Write(dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[i] + " | ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }
```

Output:

id | netMask | gateway | jenkinsUrl | bridge | ipRange |

1 | 22 | 10.19.0.1 | http://10.19.0.20:31000 | br0 | 10.19.0.1-10.19.3.254 |

11 | 22 | 10.23.0.1 | http://10.12.3.12:33355 | br2 | 10.23.0.4-10.23.0.20 |

Seems, that the data table is filled

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov Don't use a DataTable! They're far harder to work with than a nice strongly typed object.

Comment: @mason could you recommend any another alternative, right now I have 3 scenario, show as json,yaml and table (for table I chose DataTable). But if you have other suggestion. Please propose