# How to Convert JSON Data to DataTable

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON data as below:

```
{
"Data":[
    {
        "Customer":"C1",
        "ID":"11111",
        "Desc":"Row 1",
        "Price":"123456"
    },
    {
        "Customer":"C2",
        "ID":"22222",
        "Desc":"Row 2",
        "Price":"789012"
    },
    {
        "Customer":"C3",
        "ID":"33333",
        "Desc":"Row 3",
        "Price":"345678"
    }
],
"Success":true
}
```

How can I convert this data into a C# DataTable as like as this table

```
---------------------------------------------
Customer    |  ID       |  Desc    |   Price  
---------------------------------------------
C1          | 11111     | Row 1    |  123456   
C2          | 22222     | Row 2    |  789012   
C3          | 33333     | Row 3    |  345678
```

and also read **Success** value in to a variable

I want to use **Success** Variable in my code and display the table in a gridview.

I have tried this code but it's not working:

```
DataTable gdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(result);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)

Comment: The data table is nested inside a `Data` property so use `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(result, new { Data = default(DataTable) })?.Data;`.  Do you need an answer still?

Comment: If you also need `Success` you can do `var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(result, new { Data = default(DataTable), Success = default(bool) });`.  Or define an explicit root data model with `Data` and `Succes` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET [supports serializing data tables](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm) as a array of objects, however the data table in your JSON is nested inside a `"Data"` property so you need to wrap the `DataTable` in some root object.  An anonymous object should be sufficient:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(result, new { Data = default(DataTable), Success = default(bool) });
var gdata = root?.Data;
var success = root?.Success ?? false;
```

Alternatively you could introduce a generic root model like so:

```
public class DataRoot<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

And do:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataRoot<DataTable>>(result);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e7XU9q).