# convert json to datatable in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net, deserialization

```
{
  "data": [
        {
            "sheetname": "Sheet1",
            "datas": [
                {
                    "cloumn1": "6986",
                    "cloumn2": "1",
                    "cloumn3": "Server01"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sheetname": "Sheet2",
            "datas": [
                {
                    "cloumn1": "6986",
                    "cloumn2": "1",
                    "cloumn3": "Server01"
                },
                {
                    "cloumn1": "6986",
                    "cloumn2": "1",
                    "cloumn3": "Server01"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to convert this json into datatable? 
Condition:

1. Every item in "Data" attribute should be in different tab.(in above example there are 2 items so 2 worksheets should be created)
2. If "datas" attaribute contain 1 object --->1 row in 1 sheet
3. If "datas" attaribute contain 2 object --->2 rows in 1 sheet

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize your jsonstring to some class

```
List<User> UserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonString);
```

Write following [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable) to your project

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
TpeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
DataTable table = new DataTable();
for(int i = 0 ; i < props.Count ; i++)
{
    PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
}
object[] values = new object[props.Count];
foreach (T item in data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
    }
    table.Rows.Add(values);
}
return table;        
}
```

Call extension method like

```
UserList.ToDataTable<User>();
```

This code is taken from here: [Convert JSON to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)