# How to deserialize JSON object to DataTable

Tags: c#, json, datatable, deserialization

I have JSON data as below. I would like to know how to deserialize JSON object to DataTable. Please check the below JSON string and advise how to do this.

```
{
    "response":
    {
        "uri":"\/api\/junaid@khindia.com\/Gloves",
        "action":"EXPORT",
        "result":
        {
            "column_order":["AttendanceDate","DivCode","Division","DeptCode","Department","Section","CostType","Gender","Religion","EmpLevel","DegLevel","CurrentSection","EmployeeCode","EmployeeName","Strength","Presents","Absents","LayOffs","Weaving","Wallet","OutSide","PresentIn","PresentOut","AbsentIn","AbsentOut","LayoffIn","LayoffOut","Attendance","Working","LastUpDatedDate","Stage","AreaName","AreaDirection","AreaSerial","ImageURL","ShiftCode","ShiftTime","CurrentDepartment","CurrentDivision","C%_StaffOrWorker","C%_MajorDivision","M_Division","Worked_Hours","Worked_OtHours","Lateby","Earlyby","OverTime1","OverTime2","C%_OtherDivision","C%_ShiftFrom"],
            "rows":[
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AM","Leather Goods","MC","Bags","Production","Direct","Female","Hindus","Worker","Upto X","Arind","12519","SANGEETHA. M","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","P","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","","Arappakam","A         ","-2","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/12519.JPG","30","07:00 - 15:30","Bags","Bags","Worker","Bags","Leather Goods","6.28","2.5","103","0","150","0","Bags","2022-05-05 07:00:00"],
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AM","Leather Goods","MB","Wallet","Production","Direct","Male","Muslims","Worker","Degree","Arind","12548","MD NAIMUDDEEN.R","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","P","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","","Kaspa","V         ","17","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/12548.JPG","30","07:00 - 15:30","Wallet","Wallet","Worker","Wallet","Leather Goods","7.08","1.5","55","0","90","0","Wallet","2022-05-05 07:00:00"],
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AM","Leather Goods","MB","Wallet","Production","Direct","Female","Hindus","Worker","Upto XII","Arind","12567","SWETHA.P","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","P","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","","Melakuppam","A         ","-4","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/12567.JPG","30","07:00 - 15:30","Wallet","Wallet","Worker","Wallet","Leather Goods","7.13","1.5","52","0","90","0","Wallet","2022-05-05 07:00:00"],
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AM","Leather Goods","MB","Wallet","Production","Direct","Male","Muslims","Worker","Upto V","Arind","12605","IRFAN AHMED.C","1","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","A","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","","Pernambet","V         ","0","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/12605.JPG","30","07:00 - 15:30","Wallet","Wallet","Worker","Wallet","Leather Goods","0","0","0","0","0","0","Wallet","2022-05-05 07:00:00"],
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AM","Leather Goods","MD","Belts","Edge Inking","Direct","Male","Hindus","Worker","Upto X","Arind","12633","SIVAKUMAR.S","1","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","A","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","","Perumugai","V         ","0","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/12633.JPG","30","07:00 - 15:30","Belts","Belts","Worker","Belts","Leather Goods","0","0","0","0","0","0","Belts","2022-05-05 07:00:00"],
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AF","Assembly","FA","Pre-Sewing","Applique Stitch","Direct","Male","Hindus","Worker","Upto X","Arind","12940","KULOTHUNGAN. G","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","P","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","PreSewing","Sathuvachari","V         ","6","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/12940.JPG","32","08:00 - 16:30","Pre-Sewing","Gloves","Worker","Gloves","Gloves","8","0","0","0","0","0","Gloves","2022-05-05 08:00:00"],
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AM","Leather Goods","MD","Belts","Preparation","Direct","Female","Hindus","Worker","Upto X","Arind","11830","ASWINI","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","P","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","","Pillaiyar Kuppam","A         ","-1","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/11830.JPG","30","07:00 - 15:30","Belts","Belts","Worker","Belts","Leather Goods","8","0","0","0","0","0","Belts","2022-05-05 07:00:00"],
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AP","Training","PA","Training","Training","Direct","Female","Hindus","Worker","Upto X","Arind","12957","NALINI.R","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","P","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","","Melvisharam","A         ","-9","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/12957.JPG","30","07:00 - 15:30","Training","Training","Worker","Training","Training","7.1","1.5","54","0","90","0","Training","2022-05-05 07:00:00"],
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AM","Leather Goods","MA","Weaving","Weaving","Direct","Female","Hindus","Worker","Upto XII","Arind","12818","HEMALATHA.R","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","P","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","","Melakuppam","A         ","-4","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/12818.JPG","30","07:00 - 15:30","Weaving","Weaving","Worker","Weaving","Leather Goods","6.17","2.5","110","0","150","0","Weaving","2022-05-05 07:00:00"],
                ["05/05/2022 00:00:00","AM","Leather Goods","MD","Belts","Sample","Indirect","Female","Hindus","Worker","Upto X","Arind","11869","KALPANA.K","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","P","Gloves","05/05/2022 20:15:00","","Arappakam","A         ","-2","http:\/\/103.76.188.138:85\/EmployeePhotos\/11869.JPG","30","07:00 - 15:30","Belts","Belts","Worker","Belts","Leather Goods","8","0","0","0","0","0","Belts","2022-05-05 07:00:00"]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to convert only `"rows"` json array to datatable? if not, better create `c#` object model

Comment: I would like to convert rows and column and bind it to Grid control (C#).

Comment: anyway, you need to parse json to object first, then create DataTable

Comment: can you please provide code for above json in C#

Comment: You can take a look at this post which is helpful in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct an object model using one of the countless conversion utilities or even the capability to paste JSON as a class that is built into Visual Studio. (Have you even *tried* to do this?)

```cs
    public class Response
    {
        public string uri { get; set; }
        public string action { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public List<string> column_order { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }
```

Then parse the data. Assuming the JSON is in a string this is trivial.

```cs
var response = System.Text.Json.JsonSeralizer.Deserialize<Root>(jsonString).Response;
```

Then iterate the values of `response.Result` and populate your data table object. Since you haven't seen fit to provide details of that you can't have details for that part of the answer.

Incidentally, your JSON is invalid, it's missing a trailing brace.

Answer (score 1):

1. Deserialize json.
2. Get `colNames` array from `response["response"]["result"]["column_order"]`.
3. Get `rows` array from `response["response"]["result"]["rows"]`.
4. Create Datatable with configure the columns with `colNames`.
5. Add DataRow with `rows` based on `colNames` sequence.

```cs
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject response = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray colNames = response["response"]["result"]["column_order"] as JArray;
JArray rows = response["response"]["result"]["rows"] as JArray;
        
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        
foreach (var col in colNames)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(col.ToString(), typeof(string)); 
}
        
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var newRow = dt.NewRow();
        
    for (int i = 0; i < colNames.Count; i++)
    {
        var col = colNames[i].ToString();
        newRow[col] = row[i];
    }
            
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KZbz6r)

---

You may also apply the convert to Datatable logic as an extension/helper method if you also handle the data with a similar structure:

```cs
JObject response = JObject.Parse(json);
List<string> colNames = (response["response"]["result"]["column_order"] as JArray).ToObject<List<string>>();
List<List<string>> rows = (response["response"]["result"]["rows"] as JArray).ToObject<List<List<string>>>();
        
DataTable dt = DataTableExtensions.ToDataTable(colNames, rows);
```

```cs
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(List<string> colNames, List<List<string>> rows)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        
        foreach (var col in colNames)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));    
        }
        
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            var newRow = dt.NewRow();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < colNames.Count; i++)
            {
                var col = colNames[i];
                newRow[col] = row[i];
            }
            
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        
        return dt;
    }
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle Demo (As extension/helper)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3AdpfI)

Answer (score 0):

Your object is:

```
public class Response
{
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<string> column_order { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> rows { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `Newtonsoft.Json` to parse it like:

```
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Then create `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Clear();

foreach(var column in root.response.result.column_order) {
    dt.Columns.Add(column);
}

foreach(var jsonRow in root.response.result.rows) {
    for(int i =0; i < jsonRow.Length; i++) {
         DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
         row[i] = jsonRow[i];
         dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```