# How to convert a json with nested properties to data table in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

How can I convert a Json with nested properties into a `DataTable` for export as a csv file in a generic manner using c#.  A sample json as follows:

```
{
  "Length": {
    "Value": 12.93,
    "Unit": "m"
  },
  "Temperature": {
    "Value": 28.32,
    "Unit": "DegC"
  },
  "Color": "Blue"
}
```

which I would like to flatten out in a table as follows:

```
"Property"    | "Value"  | "Unit"
---------------------------------
"Length"      | 12.93    | "m"
"Temperature" | 28.32    | "DegC"
"Color"       | "Blue"   |
```

Note that the `Color` property is not nested whereas the `Length` and `Temperature` properties are.  In the case of a unit-less property such as `Color` nothing (or null) should be added to the "Unit" column in the data table.

Additionally the nested properties would mostly be of type `double`, but could contain any `struct` type.

[Convert JSON to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable) 's solution is the closest I have come, but of course does not work for the nested properties I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

```
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);

    var jsonArr = new JArray();

    foreach (var prop in jsonParsed.Properties())
    {
        var jObj = new JObject { ["Property"] = prop.Name };

        var valueType = prop.Value.GetType().Name;

        if (valueType == "JValue")
        {
            jObj["Value"] = (string)prop.Value;
            jObj["Unit"] = string.Empty;
        }
        else if (valueType == "JObject")
        {
            var nestedProp = (JObject)prop.Value;
            jObj["Value"] = (string)nestedProp["Value"];
            jObj["Unit"] = nestedProp["Unit"];
        }

        jsonArr.Add(jObj);
    }
    DataTable dataTable = jsonArr.ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Comment: Hi @Serge.  I eventually solved it like below, but I tested your answer which is of course also suitable.  Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved it directly by creating a `DataTable` and populating it as follows:

```
DataTable dataTable = new();

DataColumn[] dataColumns = new DataColumn[3];
dataColumns[0] = new DataColumn("Property");
dataColumns[1] = new DataColumn("Value");
dataColumns[2] = new DataColumn("Unit");

dataTable.Columns.AddRange(dataColumns);

JToken json = JToken.Parse(jsonContent);

foreach (JProperty content in json)
{
    DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

    row["Property"] = content.Name;

    if (content.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        row["Value"] = content.Value["Value"];
        row["Unit"] = content.Value["Unit"];
    }
    else
    {
        row["Value"] = content.Value;
        row["Unit"] = "-";
    }

    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```