# How to transform json single Key/Value pairs into DataTable?

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I have a `json` string which contains key/value pairs. Now, I want to convert the `key/value` pairs into `DataTable` with `Columns` `(key,value)`

Following is the `json` string:

```
{  
   "wifi_result":"1",
   "mic_result":"1",
   "video_result":"1",
   "touch_result":"1",
   "proximity_result":"1",
   "vibrator_result":"1",
   "power_key":"2",
   "accelerometer":"0",
   "earphone":"1",
   "memory_result":"1",
   "memory_internalSD":"1",
   "memory_internalSDSize":"25.0GB",
   "memory_externalSD":"0",
   "memory_externalSDSize":"",
   "memory_internalflash":"1",
   "memory_internalflashSize":"2.0GB",
   "memory_ram":"1",
   "memory_ramsize":"2.0GB",
   "lcd_result":"1",
   "lcd_broken":"1",
   "key_result":"1",
   "vol_key_up":"1",
   "vol_key_down":"0",
   "menu_key":"1",
   "headset_result":"1",
   "headset_leftearphone":"1",
   "headset_rightearphone":"0",
   "camera_result":"1",
   "camera_cameracount":"1",
   "camera_frontcam":"0",
   "camera_backcam":"0",
   "battery_result":"1",
   "battery_type":"1",
   "battery_level":"83",
   "battery_status":"1",
   "battery_voltage":"4204",
   "battery_temperature":"310",
   "battery_accharging":"0",
   "battery_usbcharging":"1",
   "audio_result":"1",
   "home_key":"1",
   "back_key":"1"
}
```

**Required Output:**

`DataTable` rows must be :

```
Key          |  Value
wifi_result  |    1
mic_result   |    1
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert json into datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641004/how-to-convert-json-into-datatable)

Comment: hi @utility its not the duplicate you can see that its a plain json. Not the Array.

Comment: Whats wrong with this question? 

don't knw why people go on down voting atleast they would have been wrote a comment as the reason or leave the thread if don't know any solution :(

Comment: may be because there are lot of questions related already asked at stackoverflow and your question dont make any significant point or issue than others..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a DataTable for this. In fact, it is a `Dictionary<string,string>`

Using [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var  dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);
```

Now you have the key/value pairs.

If DataTable is a must, then

```
var dt = JArray.FromObject(dict.Select(x => x)).ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first deserializing into a c# class, and then turning it into a datatable.

OR

It is possible to go directly to a datatable, with [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) 
Ex-:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```