# json string to datatable

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, datatable

I got the json result as follows.

```
{  
   "HTTPStatusCode":"200",
   "objFeedBackManagmentViewModel":[  
      {  
         "ID":2,
         "FeedBackDetail":"Email :trupti.undirwade@gandhibagh.com Mobile :9503628985 Category :Product Request Message :lookingFor",
         "CreateDate":"2015-09-04T13:42:45"
      },
      {  
         "ID":3,
         "FeedBackDetail":"Email :sujatakullarkar@gmail.com Mobile :9503507124 Category :Product Request Message :lookingFor",
         "CreateDate":"2015-09-04T18:06:44"
      }
   ]
}
```

how to convert it into datatable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert json into datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641004/how-to-convert-json-into-datatable)  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11981282/1070452

Comment: Not a strict duplication as this JSON would need a child table to take the objects in 'objFeedBackManagmentViewModel'. You'd need a DataSet surely?

Answer (score 0):

Require dll refernce from [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are trying to convert the `objFeedBackManagmentViewModel` model into a `DataTable`. Right?

So, if you follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11982180/1188208) post as @Plutonix suggested, You'll get the answer.

In summary:

1) First, Deserialize the `JSON` using some appropriate classes:

```
public class OKStatus{
    public int HTTPStatusCode {get; set;}
    public FeedBack[] objFeedBackManagmentViewModel {get; set;}
}

public class FeedBack{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string FeedBackDetail {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreateDate {get; set;}      
}
```

2) Then put the method that @Pravin Pawar gracefully provided in the post inside a `static class` like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < props.Count ; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }

        object[] values = new object[props.Count];

        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
            }

            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return table;        
    }
}
```

3) Call the method :)

```
var json = "{\"HTTPStatusCode\":\"200\",\"objFeedBackManagmentViewModel\":[{\"ID\":2,\"FeedBackDetail\":\"Email :trupti.undirwade@gandhibagh.com Mobile :9503628985 Category :Product Request Message :lookingFor\",\"CreateDate\":\"2015-09-04T13:42:45\"}]}";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OKStatus>(json);

var table = result.objFeedBackManagmentViewModel.ToDataTable(); 

//table contains the datatable of the feedback model
```

Answer (score -3):

i have no idea how to work with Json

you could try a

```
foreach(element ele in JsonNodeList)
{
}
```

i only have xml experience though

i also found this one, it might help you
[Convert JSON to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)