# Loading data to DataTable in C# gives "Unknown SQL type - 0" error

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I've been successfully using the following code to load data from an ODBC connection into a `C#` `DataTable` for some time without issues:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteSqlSelect(string sql, string connectionString)
        {
            var result = new DataTable();
            using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = sql;
                var dbReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                result.Load(dbReader);

                connection.Close();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

However, I now have a `MySql` table with a column of type `JSON`. When I try to load data from that table with that method, I get the following error:

```
Unknown SQL type - 0.
```

I assume this is because the `JSON` type is not recognized by C#'s `DataTable`. Is this correct? And more importantly: is there a solution/workaround for this?

EDIT: I'm **not** trying to convert a JSON string to a DataTable, as a commenter suggested... I'm trying to load a SQL table that contains a columns of **MySQL type 'JSON'** into a DataTable. I don't need JSON parsing, it would be fine if I just got the raw JSON string into the DataTable.

EDIT 2: both MySql and the ODBC connector are the latest version: 8.0.11

Comment: By any chance, is your code affected by this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12514

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert json into datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641004/how-to-convert-json-into-datatable)

Comment: @MoStar not a duplicate, I've edited the question to explain it better

Comment: You should provide the version of MySQL database and MySQL Connector/ODBC that you are using. Would you add this information on your question too?

Comment: @PraveenKumar well, the error message is the same, although no mention of JSON there so I'm not sure... what I do know is that if I exclude the JSON-type column from the select query it works without issues.

Comment: @Master_T Hey, in that case, have you upgraded the MySQL to the latest version that **supports JSON based data**?

Comment: @kahveci: done, thanks

Comment: I think it is more an issue of the JSON datatype not being supported by the ODBC driver.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm using the very latest version of MySql (8.0.11, on both the server and the odbc driver). As a side note: if I have a table with column type JSON I must be using a version of MySql server that supports it... otherwise I wouldn't have it :D

Comment: @Master_T Weird... And so giving up. LoL.

Comment: @PaulF: thanks for the suggestion... is this documented anywhere? I'm using the latest version of the official ODBC driver (8.0.11). Are there any versions or alternative drivers that DO support it?

Comment: My suggestion comes from this link : https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,650722,651027#msg-651027 - I couldn't find any reference to JSON datatype in the [Release Notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-odbc/en/). I don't know if modifying the query to cast the column as char/varchar is possible - if so that may be a workaround for you.

Comment: @PaulF: thanks, casting the column to CHAR worked correctly!

Comment: This has become a nice discussion. It is also suggested to CAST the JSON type to CHAR as workaround in this link: https://mysqlserverteam.com/getting-started-with-mysql-json-on-windows

Comment: @Master_T Ah great thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is more an issue of the JSON datatype not being supported by the ODBC driver - my suggestion coming from this link : https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,650722,651027#msg-651027 - I couldn't find any reference to JSON datatype in the Release Notes.

You could try casting the column to char/varchar as a workaround for you.

Comment: Thanks, accepted this because it's you that pointed me in the right direction, if anyone needs the full solution I've posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50932457/300741

Comment: You beat me to moving my comments to an answer - it is good that you have posted the updated query with the cast shown.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to PaulF's suggestion in the comments, I was able to solve this. Since the ODBC driver doesn't properly support JSON, you have to cast the column to text, directly in the query. So if before I had:

```
SELECT col1, col2, jsonCol FROM table;
```

I replaced it with:

```
SELECT col1, col2, CAST(jsonCol as CHAR(256)) as jsonCol FROM table;
```

this converts the column to normal text and it is then correctly loaded into the `DataTable`.